# I'm attempting to change data depending on the href of the link, but it only executes once

Tags: jquery

```
$("a").each(function() { openFile($(this).attr('href')); }
```

I got this from another question. openFile is a function that switches the img src depending on the file extension of the link.

now if i have this:

```
<a class="thelink" href="../General Reading/General Reading 1/Luddites/Luddites 4 Summary.pdf"><img class="theimage" src="" alt="icon"/> <div class="thefile"></div></a>
<a class="thelink" href="../General Reading/General Reading 1/Luddites/Luddites 5 Reading.pdf"><img class="theimage" src="" alt="icon"/> <div class="thefile"></div></a>
<a class="thelink" href="../General Reading/General Reading 1/Luddites/Luddites 1 Vocab.ppt"><img class="theimage" src="" alt="icon"/> <div class="thefile"></div></a>    
<a class="thelink" href="../General Reading/General Reading 1/Luddites/Luddites 2 Grammar Preview.ppt"><img class="theimage" src="" alt="icon"/> <div class="thefile"></div></a>
```

My function is only run once at the end I guess and takes the info from the last url. What I want is to loop through each link and change the info depending on that specific link.

Err hard to explain.

Comment: Put a console.log or an alert() inside the $("a").each(function() {.. and make sure that's finding the right number of elements. If it is, you might be having a problem with the openFile method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way the `openFile` function doesn't know which image to target. Maybe this will work instead?

```
$("a").each(function() {
  var src = openFile($(this).attr('href'));
  $(this).find('img').attr('src',src);
});

function openFile(href) {
  // do stuff
  // and make sure the src is returned
  return 'something';
}
```

Or add the image object to the openFile function so you can target it from there:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  openFile($(this).attr('href'), img);
});

function openFile(href, img) {
  // do stuff
  img.attr('src', something);
}
```

Or simply incorporate the `openFile` functionality to the jQuery call:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  // do stuff with $(this).attr('href')
  // change $(this).find('img').attr('src',src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you need to do the .each on the control that contains the a's?  not the 'a' control itself?

Comment: He's looping over all `a` elements in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass this as another argument to openFile, or better yet bind this to openFile by doing something like:

```
$('a').each(openFile);
```

and then

```
function openFile()
{
 //do stuff on $(this)
}
```